# keeping track of the progress of file downloads in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I asked a similar question here [AsyncTask and Progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908485/asynctask-and-progressbar).

What I am doing is I am scheduling the download of more than two files one by one in the background AsyncTask.. UI thread may need one of those files at any point of time depending upon the user interaction.. And if the file download is not complete when the UI thread asks for it, I need to show the progress of download of that particular file..

I have seen quiet a few answers about showing the progress bar of a particular file download. But my requirement is somewhat different. I need to keep track of the progress of the file downloads occurring in the background.

Comment: Why don't you follow the examples you have found, except only call `show` on the `ProgressDialog` when you need to actually show the user the progress?

Comment: I actually tried that. If the file download is not complete, I am calling the show method on progressBar which is declared in the AsyncTask.. But this doesn't work. can you help me with a code snippet of what you mean.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each download should be run on its own thread (in case one file is smaller, one server faster etc).

Try extending thread or creating a runnable that is parameterized by the URI or other identifier for the download.  Once you have that, you can invoke 2 threads that'll run until complete.  If you need to update the UI (progress bar), you will need to implement a handler and send a message from a thread to the handler. e.g.

in the main activity class:

```
   public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR =0; 
   public final Handler uiHander = new Handler(){
         public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            switch(msg.what){
            case UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR: // Something like this to handle the case of progress bar update
                 int updateAmount = msg.obj;
                 // do something to update prog. bar
                 break;
```

and then in the thread just send that message, it'll need a reference to the handler

```
     uiHander.obtainMessage(<activity name>.UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR,<integer update>).sendToTarget();
```

This may be the most portable way of doing it as async tasks implementation has changed version to version and may or may not execute both downloads in parallel (which you clearly want)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using an AsyncTask you have the option to use onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...).

E.g.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(File... file) {
     // This will call onProgressUpdate
     publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
 }

 // this will be called on the UI thread
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
 }
```

If you're not using an AsyncTask you can create a Handler and post messages to the UI thread that way.

But as you mention file downloads some things to consider (from Android docs):-

- The device might not have enough space for the expansion files, so you should check before beginning the download and warn the user if there's not enough space.
- File downloads should occur in a background service in order to avoid blocking the user interaction and allow the user to leave your app while the download completes.
- A variety of errors might occur during the request and download that you must gracefully handle.
- Network connectivity can change during the download, so you should handle such changes and if interrupted, resume the download when possible.
- While the download occurs in the background, you should provide a notification that indicates the download progress, notifies the user when it's done, and takes the user back to your application when selected.

Luckily all of the above are covered in a library from Google, which provides a download with notifications of progress (even if you quit your app). You can use it, or modify the source to your own needs. More info here

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#AboutLibraries

Comment: you mean I can call the onProgressUpdate from the UI thread?. I want to check if the file is still downloading and if it is I need to show the progressBar then. I have an array of DownloadFileTask for each file download and each has a progressBar declared inside it.. I want to do something like calling progressBar.show if the file is still downloading..

Comment: onProgressUpdate will be called from the UI thread, Android handles this for you as part of the AsyncTask implementation. Therefore, you're safe to call progressBar.show from within there when your logic determines it's necessary.

Comment: hey Ryan, I tried it and it almost worked. The only problem now I have is when I call the progressBar.show from the UI thread, it is not blocking the UI thread and instead it is executing the rest of the code.. I want the UI thread to wait until the progress finishes and closes.. is it possible?.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly? It is highly advised (by Android, not me ;-)) not to block the UI thread while doing network activity such as downloading files. In fact iirc since SDK 11 Android forces this activity in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DownloadManager` but it won't show progress in your Views. Other option is use an `ExecutorService` and submit custom `Runnable` tasks. Wrap `ExecutorService` in a custom class that maintains a map of tasks submitted. Whenever a file is needed you can query this class whether a task is completed or not, and also show a ListView of running tasks.